# Manually run model binding on relative OData url in .NET Core middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

Is there any way to manually parse OData url like it done on model binding layer?

```
/Group(odataUrl='GetLocaData(id=1)',groupColumns=['Category'],groupsExpand=@groupsExpand,aggregatedInfo=@aggregatedInfo)?$orderby=Category,Name&$top=100&$count=true&@groupsExpand=%7B%22DefaultExpanded%22:false,%22ToggledGroups%22:%5B%5D%7D&@aggregatedInfo=%7B%22AggregatedColumns%22:%5B%5D%7D
```

Thats the URL in my middleware wwhich I would like to parse in OData way and get every parameter, eg odataUrl, groupColumns, etc

Comment: This requires Edm context but may help : [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib/use-uri-parser)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to EDM on this level. Moreover, I would like it - as my middleware should behave like controller with $filter, $count